# Mockery not executing mock method

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5, mockery

I have class Name `Validator` and it has a method `forVote`.
This is my code.

```
public function test_should_set_default()
    {
        $this->mock = \Mockery::mock(Validator::class);
        $this->mock->shouldReceive('forVote')
            ->andReturnTrue();
        $this->app->instance(Validator::class,$this->mock);
        $factory = new Factory();
        $this->assertTrue($factory->setDefault());
    }
```

So `Factory` calls `Processor` which calls `Validator`. Now I want mock validator to run. But it calls the real method.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container#introduction

> since the repository is injected, we are able to easily swap it out
>   with another implementation. We are also able to easily "mock", or
>   create a dummy implementation of the `UserRepository` when testing our
>   application.

My guess is you are perhaps currently instantiating your dependencies like so:

`$processor = new Processor()` and `$validator = Validator::make(...);`

So, in order to have your mocked class be used, you should use Dependency injection which just means your classes should inject your dependencies via the `__construct` method.

Your `Factory` class should be like:

```
class Factory {

   $processor;

   public function __construct(Processor $processor)
   {
       $this->processor = $processor;
   }

   public function setDefault()
   {
       $this->processor->callingValidator();
   }
}
```

and your `Processor` to be like:

```
class Processor {

   $validator;

   /**
    * The Validator will resolve to your mocked class.
    *
    */
   public function __construct(Validator $validator)
   {
       $this->validator = $validator;
   }

   public function callingValidator()
   {
       $this->validator->make();
   }
}
```

Comment: Ohh..that's how they are done,what if it's not the case that is
dependencies are instantiated in construct(without passing as parameter). Then what should be done? Also what to do when we have to test controllers? As we simply can send http request along with data?

Comment: @SachinSharma What should be done... is that you should refactor your code to pass them via constructor.  And to test controllers and send GET/POST data... read this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/http-tests#testing-json-apis - If my answer helped, please mark it correct. Thanks. 